# How do I reshape a dataset with if statements in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in this format:

```
ID Sex Age Test1Date  Test1results Test1retakedate Test1retakeresult 

1   F   18  7/25/2000    60         1/1/2001           70              
2   M   19  7/25/2000    61         2/5/2002           90               
3   M   17  2/5/2000     70         5/7/2000           100
```

mm/dd/YYYY,
What i want to do is bring it in this format:

```
ID Sex Age TestDates Test1Results  test1retakenresults
1   F  18   7/25/2000     60               NA
1   F  18   1/1/2001      NA               70
2   M  19   7/25/2000     61               NA         
3   M  17   2/5/2000      70               NA
3   M  17   5/7/2000      NA              100
```

There are a few conditions: if the date of retakes is within a year of the test dates then the results of the retake examination i want them to appear. If not proceed to the next.
one. My issues are that i don't know how to put the values from the many different columns into one. As you can see the dates have to be in one column, same applies to the rest.

Comment: I replaced your "#" with `NA`... which is the "null" value for observations

Comment: Thank you! I also looked the formatting and I realized what i was doing it wrong and why it didn't look like that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend populating a new dataframe, which would allow you to both consolidate the data into columns and rename the columns.

```
df    <- # Your Current Dataframe
newDF <- data.frame(ID = 0,  Sex = 0, Age = 0, TestDates = 0, test1Results = 0, test1retakenresults = 0)


j <- 1                               # j loops through new dataframe

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {              # i loops through old dataframe

   newDF[j,] <- c(df[i,][1:5], NA)   # Copy old row

   if (isWithinYear(df$Test1Date[i], df$Test1retakedate[i])) {

      # Add new row if the test dates are within a year
      newDF <- rbind(newDF[1:j,], unlist(c(df[i,][1:3], df$Test1retakedate[i], 
                                     NA, df$Test1retakeresult[i])))
      j <- j + 1
    } 
 j <- j + 1
}
```

In case you don't already have an isWithinYear function I created one using the date package

```
isWithinYear <- function(date1, date2) {  

  require(date)

  rawDate <- strptime(date.mmddyyyy(as.date(date1)), "%m/%d/%Y") - 
             strptime(date.mmddyyyy(as.date(date2)), "%m/%d/%Y")

  if (abs(as.integer(rawDate)) < 365) TRUE else FALSE

 }
```

Comment: I am going to try it right now...will you be online for quite some time?

Comment: Yes, I'll help as best as I can

Comment: i hope i don't be a little bit annoying...would you like to work it through skype ?  Thank you...cause typing take a long time. It is Hercules Ap on skype Thank you

Comment: ewDF[j,] <- c(df[i,][1:5], NA)  : in this part for example i dont know what the 1:5 is... combining the df[i] and for the first 5 rows? i am not sure...

Comment: It takes the first five column values (ID, Sex, Age, Test1Date,  Test1results) from the original data structure and moves them into the new dataframe

Comment: thank you... I would really like if you would like to go on a skype session with me about...if not or yes please let me know, I honestly am desperate to make this thing work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr` to pull all the test dates into the same column:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("ID Sex Age Test1Date  Test1results Test1retakedate Test1retakeresult 
1   F   18  7/25/2000    60         1/1/2001           70              
2   M   19  7/25/2000    61         2/5/2002           90               
3   M   17  2/5/2000     70         5/7/2000           100    "), header = TRUE)

library(tidyr)

gather(df,vals,TestDates,contains("ate"))

  ID Sex Age Test1results Test1retakeresult            vals TestDates
1  1   F  18           60                70       Test1Date 7/25/2000
2  1   F  18           60                70 Test1retakedate  1/1/2001
3  2   M  19           61                90       Test1Date 7/25/2000
4  2   M  19           61                90 Test1retakedate  2/5/2002
5  3   M  17           70               100       Test1Date  2/5/2000
6  3   M  17           70               100 Test1retakedate  5/7/2000
```

That should make it easier to implement the rest of your steps.

Comment: but i don't want the same test results to appear on more than 1 row. Also it would be difficult after to disregard the dates that are more than a year from the 1st examination, and their corresponding test results.

Bear in mind that there are at least 10 more dates in the original dataset with their respective results.